# git reflog references pruned commits, but does not show the reflog for the branch

Tags: git

git gc shows:

```
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/origin/abc_branch' references pruned commits
```

But, when I try to see the reflog, I get nothing:

```
$ git reflog show origin/abc_branch@{0}

fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/abc_branch@{0}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

I know the syntax is right, because that happened to another branch and I was able to see the reflog - and remove it.

The abc_branch has been deleted on the remote without being merged - commits deleted. I don't want to recover it, I just want to get rid of the warning.

Comment: `git reflog show --all` does not show the branch.

Comment: Neither does `git reflog expire --dry-run --expire=now --all`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the `abc_branch` ref, you could try:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/abc_branch
```